# RGB to grey using scikit-learn manifold

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to reduce the dimensions to turn a RGB image to grey using [manifold learning methods](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_compare_methods.html#example-manifold-plot-compare-methods-py).

I have converted an image into a numpy array (image_array)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
china = load_sample_image("china.jpg")

# Convert to floats instead of the default 8 bits integer coding. Dividing by
# 255 is important so that plt.imshow behaves works well on float data (need to
# be in the range [0-1]

china = np.arraychina, dtype=np.float64) / 255

# Load Image and transform to a 2D numpy array.

w, h, d = original_shape = tuple(china.shape)
assert d == 3
image_array = np.reshape(china, (w * h, d))
```

Inspect image_array

```
image_array.shape
```

> (273280, 3)

When trying,

```
X, color = image_array
```

I get

> ValueError: too many values to unpack.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
china = (china[:,:,:3] * [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]).sum(axis=2)
```

Which is what I did in my diy machine learning (I found pure numpy was significantly faster than using scikit, including a version of oriented histogram of gradients see https://github.com/paddywwoof/Machine-Learning/blob/master/image_processor.py)

Comment: Thank you!

The thing is that I am looking at various ways to convert RGB to grey. I have a Matlab file with different conversion algorithms - including a weighted conversion as yours, and a principal component analysis (PCA).

Now I would like to try how other dimensionality reduction algorithms performs compared to those methods. To make it easier to share code I wanted to switch to Python.
Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: OK, when you have something shareable I would be interested in seeing it. Is it on github yet? Maybe you're not fully up to speed with python and numpy then.. The error in your original post was because you create a numpy array image_array which is, as you demonstrate, 273280 rows by 3 columns then you try to coerce it into a tuple with only two elements. It doesn't fit!! What are you trying to get into your X and color variables?